# How to update theme in Opencart

Tags: opencart

I want to update the Journal theme in Opencart. The version that I have now is 3.0.7 and I want to update the version 3.0.33 with the same Database.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. What is your exact question ? What have you tried to make this upgrade and what is the exact problem you are facing ? Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Journal is a paid theme - ask them.